# Ресет SVG анимации

Tags: svg, svg-animation, smil

Можно ли только с помощью SMIL анимации плавно вернуть SVG к изначальному состоянию (при втором клике на окружность)?

1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
svg {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Слой_1" x="0" y="0" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 130 130" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs/>
  <style>
    .st1{fill:#d7d7d7}
  </style>
  <circle id="cr1" cx="65" cy="65" r="65" fill="#f3f3f4"/>   
  <path id="l1" d="M106.8 46.5H23.2c-1.7 0-3.2-1.3-3.2-3s1.4-3 3.2-3h83.7c1.7 0 3.2 1.3 3.2 3s-1.5 3-3.3 3z" class="st1"/>
  <path id="l2" d="M106.8 68H23.2c-1.7 0-3.2-1.3-3.2-3s1.4-3 3.2-3h83.7c1.7 0 3.2 1.3 3.2 3s-1.5 3-3.3 3z" class="st1"/>
  <path id="l3" d="M106.8 89.5H23.2c-1.7 0-3.2-1.3-3.2-3s1.4-3 3.2-3h83.7c1.7 0 3.2 1.3 3.2 3s-1.5 3-3.3 3z" class="st1"/>
 
<animate
 xlink:href="#cr1"
           attributeName="cx"
           from="65"
           to="65" 
           dur="1s"
           begin="click"
           fill="freeze"
      id = "cr_anim"/>
 
<animate
 xlink:href="#l1"
           attributeName="d"
           from="M106.8 46.5H23.2c-1.7 0-3.2-1.3-3.2-3s1.4-3 3.2-3h83.7c1.7 0 3.2 1.3 3.2 3s-1.5 3-3.3 3z"
           to="M106.8 68H23.2c-1.7 0-3.2-1.3-3.2-3s1.4-3 3.2-3h83.7c1.7 0 3.2 1.3 3.2 3s-1.5 3-3.3 3z" 
           dur="0.5s"
           begin="cr_anim.begin"
           fill="freeze"
      id = "l1_anim"/>
      
<animate
          xlink:href="#l3"
           attributeName="d"
           from="M106.8 89.5H23.2c-1.7 0-3.2-1.3-3.2-3s1.4-3 3.2-3h83.7c1.7 0 3.2 1.3 3.2 3s-1.5 3-3.3 3z"
           to="M106.8 68H23.2c-1.7 0-3.2-1.3-3.2-3s1.4-3 3.2-3h83.7c1.7 0 3.2 1.3 3.2 3s-1.5 3-3.3 3z" 
           dur="0.5s"
           begin="l1_anim.begin"
           fill="freeze"
      id = "l3_anim"/>
      
<animateTransform
          xlink:href="#l1"
           attributeName="transform" 
           attributeType="XML"
           type="rotate"
           from="0 65 65"
           to="45 65 65" 
           dur="0.5s"
           begin="cr_anim.begin + 0.5s"
           fill="freeze"
      id = "l1_anim2"/>
      
<animateTransform
          xlink:href="#l2"
           attributeName="transform" 
           attributeType="XML"
           type="rotate"
           from="0 65 65"
           to="45 65 65" 
           dur="0.5s"
           begin="cr_anim.begin + 0.5s"
           fill="freeze"
      id = "l2_anim"/>
      
<animateTransform
          xlink:href="#l3"
           attributeName="transform" 
           attributeType="XML"
           type="rotate"
           from="0 65 65"
           to="-45 65 65" 
           dur="0.5s"
           begin="cr_anim.begin + 0.5s"
           fill="freeze"
      id = "l3_anim2"/>
      
      

</svg>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Ого, буду ждать)

Comment: https://codepen.io/mikemjharris/pen/qdZeGY

Comment: https://codepen.io/mikemjharris/post/svg-toggling